# What is the status of IndexDB support across browsers?

Tags: html, indexeddb

Apparently the SQL storage is deprecated by W3C (thankfully), and the IndexedDB seems to be the recommendation.  On the other hand, I've come across things like the following:

var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;

Which concerns me.

Is IE supported?  What is the level of support for the various browsers?  I can't seem to find a page that lists this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a compatibility table for support of IndexedDB in desktop and mobile browsers.: http://caniuse.com/indexeddb